# How do I select only one row based on student's phone type priority

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Hello and thank you for helping me.

A student can have multiple email addresses where the type is: personal, work, other, school

I need to write a query that select one email address for a student. If a student has more than one email address, then the email address selected needs to be based on the email type of the email addresses.

For example,

- If a student has a personal email then I select only the personal email.
- If a student does not have a personal email but has the other email types then I will select their school email address.

The priority order of the email types are: personal, school, work, other. The goal is to select only one record based on the priority list (personal, school, work, and then other)

Student table structure

```
student_id
email_type
email_addr
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions and a `case` expression:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by student_id 
            order by case email_type 
                when 'personal' then 1
                when 'school' then 2
                when 'work' then 3
                else 4
            end 
        ) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

In Oracle, you can shorten this with `decode()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by student_id 
            order by decode(email_type, 'personal', 1, 'school', 2, 'work', 3, 4)
        ) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Another typical solution is `fetch first row with ties`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
order by row_number() over(
    partition by student_id 
    order by decode(email_type, 'personal', 1, 'school', 2, 'work', 3, 4)
)
fetch first row with ties
```

Comment: Wow - Thank yo so much. It works !!! I I want to add another table and join mytable to it . How do I do that to your solution   select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by student_id 
            order by decode(email_type, 'personal', 1, 'school', 2, 'work', 3, 4)
        ) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1

Comment: @Lucy: well, just join in the outer query, as you would in any other query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an analytic function with `KEEP`:

```sql
SELECT student_id,
       MAX( email_type ) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK FIRST
         ORDER BY DECODE( email_type, 'personal', 1, 'school', 2, 'work', 3, 4 )
       ) AS email_type,
       MAX( email_addr ) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK FIRST
         ORDER BY DECODE( email_type, 'personal', 1, 'school', 2, 'work', 3, 4 )
       ) AS email_addr
FROM   student
GROUP BY student_id
```

For some test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE student ( student_id, email_type, email_addr ) AS
SELECT 1, 'school',   'person1@school' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'work',     'person1@work'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'other',    'person1@other'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'personal', 'person2@home'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'other',    'person2@other'  FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> STUDENT_ID | EMAIL_TYPE | EMAIL_ADDR    
> ---------: | :--------- | :-------------
>          1 | school     | person1@school
>          2 | personal   | person2@home
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fffe53f9c7c71b94075024bab0c66230)*

Comment: This information is very helpful and thank you so much for your time. I am not sure if I can replicate this is PS Query.